I want to fix my rhythm problems
Let me first tell you about myself - a 29 y.o that started playing guitar at 13 and went to a music school (2 years) and then to a music college (4 years).
I am not a person that has "built-in" ability to sing, transcribe songs by ear or being able to reproduce some rhythm exercise. Despite that I worked hard and can do all of these things now, but there is one problem that has been bothering me all those years since I started recording myself: playing off the beat (see the image).
The top track is 120bmp click track and the bottom one is me clapping on every beat - as you can see I don't play exactly on beat - sometimes there is even up to 100ms difference (can be both: too soon or too early). Of course when I play a musical instrument I can see and hear where I didn't play on time as well.

My first question is: how do you call playing like that in English? I've searched "playing off beat", "playing out of tempo", but I don't think they describe my issue.
My second question: Do you know how I could fix this issue and play more accurately?

Welcome! These two questions really get separate answers, even though they're on the same topic, so please edit to ask the "what do you call it" question in a separate post. (No harm in copy/pasting the image and explanation.) Many questions about language would be a better fit at https://ell.stackexchange.com/, but this is so music-specific that I think it's on-topic here. No, you don't want to use "off-beat" because that often means "placed exactly halfway between beats," like the "and" in "1 and 2 and."

See also some other related questions: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/88017/78419 https://music.stackexchange.com/q/16833/78419 https://music.stackexchange.com/q/5599/78419

Btw, are you looking at the DAW while recording? If so, your timing might be thrown off by visual input. Practice steady rhythm using visual aids (an old-fashioned pendulum metronome is a great one), but test it using audio-only.

What you see in your DAW may not be an accurate measurement of your timing.  See this question:  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107470/how-do-i-fix-a-consistent-micro-timing-error

You are aware of the issue, you are trying to measure it, which is great as self awareness is being half way there.
You can try a few things:

Rhythm is something that we feel so an important question to ask yourself is how do I feel when clapping? Am I relaxed or tense, Do I enjoy the beat, Am I in the zone for playing music? If your state of mind is - I am recording and just want to hit that next beat like a nail in the head then you're probably too tense. So see how you can perform the same clapping exercise forcing yourself into different states of mind and feels. Try to relax, or don't care, try to jump along, use your body, see it as fun. So the exercise is to get a bit more control over how do you feel when performing.

Think internally about smaller subdivisions, so instead of waiting for the next hit just imagine a hi-hat in your head and see if a steady sixteenth pulse stabilizes your sense of time.

Work with metronome but again combine this with controlling your feel and trying to be a bit behind, on the beat, a bit before the beat.

Delve more in the world of rhytms, learn latin grooves on percussion instrument, learn indian classical rythms, force yourself into a rabbit hole of rhythm and the enjoyment will follow, and with that and bit of time and practice,much better rythm feel



When you're consistently ahead of the beat, it's often called "rushing", or just "being ahead of the beat".
The only practice I know of to address this is to work with a metronome every day and listen very closely to your timing and work to be exactly on the beat. Count along with the beat and count subdivisions also (e.g., count out loud “one and two and three…” not just “one two three…”)
Note that you have to careful taking feedback from DAW recordings like this because the equipment you used to record could be the cause of the misalignment. If you know you're off time then you're probably right. If you're convinced you're on time but the DAW says you're off time, then the DAW could be wrong and you might be better than you think.
The only way to use the DAW to make sure is to record both the metronome and your clapping at the same time. You could even use a phone recording for this.

"The only way to use the DAW to make sure is to record both the metronome and your clapping at the same time."

Sorry I don't quite understand how I should record the metronome


@AvtemSerious Well at the simplest, you could use an actual physical metronome! You'd also have it in the same acoustic space as your clap then. But if you recorded with only one mic, you couldn't see the two tracks nicely separated that way. You could use two mics with adequate separation to limit bleed-through. Or you could do fancier things like routing a virtual metronome into the DAW to be laid down at the same time as your claps, but then you get into questions of whether you're hearing it at the same time that it's getting recorded...

@AndyBonner there’s no need for two mics anyway. One mic can show two separate transients as easily as two, and even without looking, when you’re not playing timing problems are usually easy to hear.

@ToddWilcox I guess. When you get close it could get hard to spot, but I guess then it's mission accomplished anyway!
